# Extending Python's namedtuple: how can I avoid the cost of subclassing?

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to add the following functionality to Python's `collections.namedtuple`

```
Lazy = namedtupleforthelazytm('Lazy', ('A', 'B'))
inst = Lazy(1, 2)
# namedtuple has this:
inst[0]
inst.A
# I want this:
SV = 'A'
inst[SV]
```

The following code appears to achieve just that

```
import collections

def namedtupleforthelazytm(classname, fieldnames):
    class lazy(collections.namedtuple(classname + '_wrapped', fieldnames)):
        __slots__ = ()
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            if key in self._fields:
                return super().__getattribute__(key)
            return super().__getitem__(key)
    lazy.__name__ = classname
    return lazy
```

The performance hit incurred, however, is drastic:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from nmdtpl import namedtupleforthelazytm
>>> 
>>> def stress(o):
...     for i in range(100000):
...         x = o[0]
...         x = o[1]
...         x = o.a
...         x = o.b
...
>>> orig = namedtuple('O', ('a', 'b'))(1, 2)
>>> subc = namedtupleforthelazytm('S', ('a', 'b'))(1, 2)
>>> 
>>> timeit('f(a)', number=10, globals={'f':stress, 'a':orig})
0.13294775993563235
>>> timeit('f(a)', number=10, globals={'f':stress, 'a':subc})
2.1330132230650634
```

My question is: Is there a way of getting the desired functionality a bit cheaper (not necessarily starting from `namedtuple`)?

Clarifications:

The beauty of `namedtuple` to me is that it makes code much more readable compared to using tuples while avoiding the cost of a full mapping.
I could use `getattr(inst, SV)`, but that kind of defeats the purpose (readability) - think nested structures if you find a single one too easy to read to warrant any action.

Comment: What is the purpose of `SV`? You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: @PeterWood it's valid *syntax*, just a `NameError` if `A` isn't defined.

Comment: If you want a mapping just use a mapping (dict).

Comment: Is the behavior you want for `inst[SV]` to work? I'd use `getattr(inst, SV)` for that, rather than trying to write a new class that supports the field names as indexes.

Comment: @Peter Wood Blckknght Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: It seems to me you want a dictionary-style mapping while also allowing attribute-style access to the dictionary values.  Do you really need ordering? Integer indexes? Try this [AttrDict class](https://github.com/kdart/pycopia3/blob/master/aid/pycopia/dictlib.py#L21).

Comment: @Keith thanks for the pointer. I'm reluctant to use a fully fledged mapping because I want it lightweight. Immutable and fixed length are perfectly acceptable for my use case.

Comment: What you have there is not lightweight, since it involves a hash-table lookup on the `self._fields` anyway.

Comment: @Keith Well, in a sense that is why I'm asking for advice. Merely out of interest: isn't attribute lookup heavily optimised in the interpreter, using for example the fact that keys are guaranteed to be strings? And what about `__slots__` (which namedtuple uses)?

Comment: The reason behind such drastic performance issue is that you've now written your `__getitem__` in pure Python. The calls like `super()`, `in` etc are going to be slow compared to `__getitem__` written in C. You could optimize it a bit by preventing these lookups, for example cache `super().__getitem__` by using `def __getitem__(self, key, getitem=cls.__getitem__)` where `cls` is `collections.namedtuple(classname + '_wrapped', fieldnames)`(something similar can be done for `super().__getattribute__`).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, that is precisely the kind of wisdom I was hoping for. You wouldn't by any chance be willing to make an answer out of this?

Comment: @PaulPanzer But function calls aren't terribly fast in Python. The `super()` calls are slow too, since it has to figure out your MRO. At least try `type.__getattribute__(self, key)` and similar for the other.

Comment: @Keith thanks, will do.

Comment: Why not `return next(value for field, value in zip(self._fields, self) if field == key)`